# 3D shadow effect paper like styling

Tags: html, css, shadow

Can i add this style to all the coners and not only at the bottoms corners ? - and if yes how can i do it. I'm trying to make it at the sides not the bottom, it should look like it is a paper there has folded each corner. If you look at the ex. 2 if you press the link. i want to add the same styling there is at the bottom to the top so all 4 corners are folded..

http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects

I have succesfully made it to the the top side corners, but i'm missing the bottom coners. heres my code..

HTML:

```css
#d {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1140px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30000;
}
.content_wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1140px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
}
.content_inner {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #baced8;
}
.effect {
  position: relative;
}
.effect:before,
.effect:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 19px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 4%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: rgba(101, 102, 103, 0.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(101, 102, 103, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(101, 102, 103, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(101, 102, 103, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 19px;
  left: auto;
}
#content_box {
  width: 1134px;
  height: 770px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="content_inner effect effect2">
      <div id="content_box">

      </div>
      <!--content_box-->
    </div>
    <!--content_inner-->
  </div>
  <!--content_wrapper-->
</div>
```

Comment: You've linked to 8 effects... which one are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jbutler483 It was example 2, but have solved it thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another element like the .content_wrapper to get yourself another two pseudo-elements. Those two are showing the shadow to the bottom.

I assume it looks the way you want it:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvmYXm

```
effect:before, .effect:after, 
  .content_wrapper:before, .content_wrapper:after {
    content: "";  
    position: absolute;  top: 4%; bottom: 40px;  left: 19px; 
    width: 50%; max-width: 300px;

    background: rgba(101,102,103,0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px rgba(101,102,103,0.9);

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
            transform: rotate(-3deg);

    z-index: -1;
  }
  .effect:after, .content_wrapper:after  {
      right: 19px;  left: auto;    
      -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
              transform: rotate(3deg);

  }

  .content_wrapper:before {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
              transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  .content_wrapper:after {
      bottom: 40px; right: 19px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
              transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
```